# What's the safest (rot-proof) way to transplant a Sansevieria cutting?

Tags: succulents, roots

Sansevierias are easy to grow and propagate. I would say that their only downside is being prone to rot upon re-rooting as cuttings.

I often take a cutting from one of the offshoots. The norm is to let the cut callus for something like two weeks before rooting it in soil. However, what if that offshoot already has roots of its own? Sure the roots can take a hold in the new potting medium, but the cut area having no time to callus will surely trigger a rot "chain reaction" which will kill the whole plant. I was thinking (still too early to try for this season) to let the offshoot callus anyway. The existing roots may dry up and new ones will grow when it is time to plant. So, is this a good idea? Or should I find a way to root it anyway but keep the cut above soil?

Few Sansevieria species have above-ground runners which develop aerial roots. They can handle being exposed to the air. However, the problem is about the other types, like the S. Trifasciata, which have all their rhizomes under the soil level. These are more rot prone.

Comment: I'm curious if anyone has tried using rooting hormone powder as a coating that might help?